# How do I add a platform template to XCode?

Tags: xcode, templates, addition, platform

When you navigate to File>New Project it gives you the templates for iOS and Mac OS X. I want to add my own platform that has templates. So it would show iOS, Mac OS X, and MY_PLATFORM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure you can "make your own platform", you can however make custom templates for use in Xcode 4.

### Some Tutorials

http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/

http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/making-custom-templates-for-xcode-4-march-2011/

**Template Assembler:** https://github.com/yonishin/XCode-4-Project-Template-Assembler-MSPS/